# DataTables change content of cell and make it searchable

Tags: datatables

I have the following. At the bottom I set the HTML of the cells depending on other values. This works. However when I search the table, rather by the in-built search or using the API (`force_table.columns(6).search(val).draw();`) it doesn't bring it back

Am I doing this incorrectly?

```
var force_table = $('#force-table').DataTable({
    "scrollY": 400,
    "scrollX": true,
    "paging": false,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    "oSearch": {"bSmart": false},
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Export to Excel',
        }
    ],
    "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
        if ( data[8] > 1) {
            $('td', row).eq(8).addClass('green');
        }
        else {
            $('td', row).eq(8).addClass('orange');
        }
         if ( data[9] > 1) {
            $('td', row).eq(9).addClass('green');
        }
        else {
            $('td', row).eq(9).addClass('orange');
        }
         if ( data[10] > 1) {
            $('td', row).eq(10).addClass('green');
        }
        else {
            $('td', row).eq(10).addClass('orange');
        }

        if ( data[9] > 1 && data[10] > 1) {
            $('td', row).eq(6).html('Yes');
        }
        else {
            $('td', row).eq(6).html('No');
        }
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `createdRow` function is good for making DOM-related changes - such as your `addClass()` examples. But it does not change the data inside the DataTables object. So, even though you can see your change displayed in the table, DataTables is not aware of it - and therefore cannot find it.

An alternative is to move your final `if/else` logic (for "yes"/"no") into the following:

```
"columnDefs": [ {
  targets: 6,
  render: function (data, type, row) {
    if ( row[9] > 1 && row[10] > 1 ) {
      return 'yes';
    } else {
      return 'no';
    }
  }
} ]
```

Instead of using a jQuery selector `$('td', row).eq(6).html(...)`, you are using the DataTables API to manage the table's data. This data can be searched/filtered.

(If you add this new section after your `createdRow` section, remember to add a comma to separate the sections.)